# Flow-type WebStorm how to show type hints on mouse hover over object variables

Tags: webstorm, flowtype

In flow-type, on mouse hover over variable of any type object we do not see type hints:

[image]

However, WebStorm does see the type is:

[image]

Searched well and played with the setting, but could not find how to tell WebStorm to expose the type hint on hover.

I want WebStorm to hint similar to how TypeScript does:

[image]
(this is TypeScript)

By the way, for string or number we get type hint for flowtype:
[image]

So, is this possible to enable object type hinting on hover with flowtype?